# Repeater ItemDataBound event gives null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am getting null exception when using itemdatabound.when I chech ,what I see is item index zero.can u tell me where my repeater is wrong

my repeater ;

```
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptKonutm" OnItemDataBound="rptKonut_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>


      <div class="caption">
      <h4 class="pull-right"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Fiyat") %>$</h4>
       <h4>
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblKonutFiyat"></asp:Label>

        </h4>
        <h4 class="pull-right"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Il")%></h4>
        <h4><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMevki"></asp:Label></h4>

          <h4 class="pull-right"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EkBilgi")%></h4>
        <h4><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDahaFazlaBilgi"></asp:Label></h4>
        <h4 class="pull-right"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AlanMetreKare")%></h4>
          <h4><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAlanMetreKare"></asp:Label></h4>
 </div>
                    <!-- Split button -->
                   </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

and code behind ItemDatabound event

```
protected void rptKonut_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblKonutFiyat = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblKonutFiyat");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblMevki = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblMevki");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblDahaFazlaBilgi = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDahaFazlaBilgi");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblAlanMetreKare = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblAlanMetreKare");


            lblKonutFiyat.Text = MyResource.lblKonutFiyat;
            lblMevki.Text = MyResource.lblMevki;
            lblDahaFazlaBilgi.Text = MyResource.lblDahaFazlaBilgi;
            lblAlanMetreKare.Text = MyResource.lblAlanMetreKare;


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imad is correct you need to check that you are searching in Item rows.

You could find your controls in the following manner to determine the cause of the error:

```
        Label lblKonutFiyat = e.Item.FindControl("lblKonutFiyat") as Label;

        if (lblKonutFiyat != null)
        {
            lblKonutFiyat.Text = MyResource.lblKonutFiyat;
        }

       ....
```

If your control is null it will gracefully handle it, any labels that aren't getting set will provide you with the problematic labels.

Comment: I mentioned my question that  item index zero which that means  all controls are  null

Comment: What was the answer/problem? :)

Comment: what conclusion I reach here ,is that,if u wanna make sure code is correct ,do it manualy ,not automatically.not at the same time both.I just forget to remove anaother repater at the top of my code,which vs automatically createed

Comment: the cost ;4 hours waste of the times

Comment: Yeah, manually is best. When I was learning I used the Visual Studio stuff and it added lots of code that I didn't really need. It's good to get something up and running quickly but once you know what is happening manual is the future. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try keeping your code in following if

```
 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem){}
```

Comment: ahh u mean label id ,okey

Comment: These labels are childs of page or repeater?

Comment: I am sorry I mistake ,I just forget a stupid tag the code above,which take my time 4 hours :(

Comment: if my **if code** helped you, please mark it as an answer to help others to find correct solution.